# How to process multipart zip file and json object using sparkjava framework

Tags: spark-java

I am trying to process both **multipart zip** file and also the **json** object from the request using `SparkJava`, but the request becomes empty once we use it parse the `zip` file and the same cannot be used to parse the `json` object.
Is there any way to accomplish this using `SparkJava`.

I am processing the zip file in the below manner

```
post("/agent/blueprint/create", (request, response) -> {
    String responseObject = null;
    if (request.raw().getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig") == null) {
        MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        request.raw().setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig", multipartConfigElement);}
        Part file = request.raw().getPart("fileStream");
        if (file.getContentType().startsWith("application/octet-stream")) {
            Part uploadedFile = request.raw().getPart("fileStream");
            InputStream inputStream = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
            ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
            ZipEntry entry = null;
            while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The request has two parts, one is a zip file and other other being json object
above code processes the attachment, next when I try to process the json object using 'request.body()', the request seems empty.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]. Please take time out for a [tour] and go through [help].

Comment: Could you post a code snippet for better understanding ?

Comment: @Laercio, I have added code snippet

Comment: Check to see what is the string you get when calling `request.body()` before you start processing the zip file.

Comment: Yes I did, In that case the zip processing throws error, its like either one of them could be processed not both

Comment: But in that case, were you able to retrieve the json ?

Comment: One more guess, maybe the problem resides in the fact that only the part of the reques that holds the zipped file has a name (fileStream). Try giving a name to the part that holds the json as well.

Comment: I was able to retrieve the json when called first, the name for the part which holds json is 'data' but after retrieving json if I try retrieving zip it throws error

Answer (score 0):

I got that, this can be achieved by using Collection for retrieving json object and loop through it

```
Collection<Part> parts = request.raw().getParts();
for (Part part : parts) {
```

and  for the zip file part use

```
Part file = request.raw().getPart("fileStream");
```